# Using pointers in Redux store

Tags: reactjs, pointers, redux

I have the following structure in my Redux store.

```
 persons: {
    1: {
       name: "John",
    },
    2: {
       name: "Erica",
    }
 };

 // First way
 companies: [{
    name: "Google",
    persons: [1, 2]
 }];

 // Second way
 companies: [{
    name: "Google",
    persons: [{
    1: {
       name: "John",
    },
    2: {
       name: "Erica",
    }
 }];
```

I want to show persons in a company however both of the practices I tried has some issues.

1. In `First way`, each time I want to look at`company.persons` attribute, I should also call `persons[id]` to obtain person information.
2. In `Second way`, each time I make a modification to the person object, I also have to update all the child objects on each parent and it can quickly become a mess.

Basically I want `companies.persons[id]` to point to `persons` attribute so I can do stuff like `companies.persons[0].name` but keep the single source of truth.

Any ideas?

Comment: Definitely keep single point of truth. If the first way is too complicated for you, create a helper function to access the people as objects. A simple `map` is all you need.

Comment: I'd agree that the first way is better - try to lay your state out as you would a database (separate collections linked by keys). And definitely make use of helper functions as @Sulthan suggested - these are often referred to as 'selectors' (see [this great video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers) by the dev of Redux himself).

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using a [Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html#normalizing-state-shape) for your store in redux.

Using this approach I would suggest you to use your first approach where I suppose you keep separate various entities, like persons and companies, and linkt theme together using an id.

```
// First way
persons: {
    1: {
       name: "John",
    },
    2: {
       name: "Erica",
    }
 };

 companies: [{
    name: "Google",
    persons: [1, 2]
 }];
```

Comment: Can't we abstract that, though? If they were classes instead of object literals I could easily put an accessor and return persons instead. This approach feels a bit limiting. :(

Comment: @Aris In redux the store is a simple plain object containing only data for your application, not sure about idea of abstraction applied to redux store. I would suggest instead to think at your store more as a database table/row relationship as indicated well in the article Normalizing State Shape suggested by the author of redux.

Comment: @Aris In case you have found my answer useful please do not forget to accept/upvote it. if you have any other questions, please ask :) thanks for your collaboration.

Comment: It definitely helps but I was looking for a better approach. Relying on dumb object literals and having to duplicate identifiers everywhere is not a good practice. (at least in my book) In worst case, I would like to find a way to make it a bit smarter. `company.persons.map(person => person.name)` is what I'm after. I will probably tweak the Redux store a bit and try to support at least basic getters. Ps. I already upvoted you but that's not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Hi. I wrote the "Normalizing State Shape" docs section.  If you don't want to _just_ use plain objects, and would like an abstraction layer to make it easier to manage those relations, I recommend using https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm.   I've written a couple posts about how I use it: [Practical Redux, Part 1: Redux-ORM Basics](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/practical-redux-part-1-redux-orm-basics/) and [Practical Redux, Part 2: Redux-ORM Techniques](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/practical-redux-part-2-redux-orm-concepts-and-techniques/).

Comment: @markerikson Wow, amazing. Thanks alot! Kudos for writing documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

This type of question probably belongs at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

With that said. My suggestion.
Split it up into two reducers and combine them with combineReducer for a cleaner way. It makes more sence to have a single "updateable" (immutable) object as root.

My suggestion would then be:

```
companies: [{
    name: "Google"
 }];

persons: {
    "Google": {
        1: { name: "John" }, 
        2: { name: "Erica" }
     }
};
```

If you need a key, or else feel free to use array as persons. I have always though maps makes better state objects and Object.keys can be easily used to iterate through them later.

Or you can ofcouse use your "method no 1" with a array of keys if that fits your backend and data structure better.

Comment: In your example, if I want to get attributes of Erica, I have to make a query from company first. Are you sure you understand the question properly?

Comment: "I want to show persons in a company"
"Any ideas?" Thats how i read the question. Like i said in the answer you could also skip the "group" key in persons and just use it via the company array.